# Why is this click event automatically triggered in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a simple app using JS/jQuery as a learning exercise and am running into a problem I've encountered before and can't seem to solve. Why, in the following code, is the second click event triggered automatically rather than when I click $('.tweet li a.username')?

```
$(function(){
   setInterval(update, 3000);
    $('.showMore').on('click', function() {
      moreIndex += 5;
      update();
    })
    $('.tweet li a.username').on('click', alert('hey!'));
  });
```

alert('hey!') is filler for a function I'm still working out. How should this be organized so that the click event triggers when the link is clicked rather than when the page loads? The $('.showMore') event works properly, even if I change the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because you are invoking the alert function there instead of passing the callback function reference.

In your case you are invoking the `alert()` function and pass the value returned by the `alert` as the click event handler.

```
$('.tweet li a.username').on('click', function(){
    alert('hey!')
});
```

Comment: Got it. Tried that before and didn't get the alert. I must just have the selector wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the alert in a callback function, just like the first example:

```
$('.tweet li a.username').on('click', function() { alert('hey!') });
```

The `.on` method is expecting a JavaScript object in that position, a function in particular, which it can execute later. What is happening in your original code is that the JavaScript engine is looking for a function, but sees some other code there instead -- so it executes the code there (activating the alert) in hopes that a useful object will be returned. (When nothing is returned, the JavaScript engine instead assumes that you want `null` to be executed on a click event, and happily does so.)